# I do not get this question at all. I need to prove the an equation has a minimum. Quadratics involved.

Tags: conic-sections, quadratics

Prove that $f(x)= (x-a)^2+(x-b)^2$ has a minimum when $x= \frac{a+b}{2}$. (Prove not verify)
I do not get this question whatsoever, please help me.

Comment: Are you permitted to use calculus?

Comment: I am pre-calculus.

Comment: Have you studied derivative test?

Comment: (1)Expand and collect to get a form like $P x^2+Q x +R$ and complete the square. OR (2) Let $x=y+(a+b)/2$ and see what you get.

Comment: Have you ever added two functions together? Did you learn any ways to determine the minimum or maximum value of a quadratic function? Do you know the formula to solve a quadratic equation? Do you know what it means to square a binomial, and how to do it? Depending on what things you already know how to do, there could be one or two quick ways to do this, or we could have to explain much more.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can attack this problem.

**Method 1**

Expand the expression, collect like terms, and get the formula into the form
$f(x)=Ax^2 + Bx + C$
(where $A, B$, and $C$ are some constants, possibly involving combinations of the $a$ and $b$ in the original problem.)  Then invoke two facts:

1. If $A$ is positive, then the graph is an upwards-pointing parabola; and
2. The vertex of that parabola occurs at $x=-B/2A$.

Both of these are facts from first-year Algebra; if you are allowed to use them, then they together tell you where the minimum of the function occurs.

**Method 2**

First, plug in the given value $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ into the formula, and compute what $f(x)$ is actually equal to for that given value.  (The value will involve $a$ and $b$.)

Next, suppose $x \ne \frac{a+b}{2}$.  Then $x=\frac{a+b}{2} + k$ for some $k\ne 0$.  Plug that into the formula for $f(x)$ and compute what the value of $f(x)$ is for all values other than the given one.  (The value will involve $a$, $b$ and $k$.)

Now compare those two results and explain why the second one must always be larger than the first one as long as $k \ne 0$.

**Method 3**

Since the function is quadratic, and the coefficient of $x^2$ in both terms is positive, the function is an upwards-pointing parabola; therefore it has to have a minimum *somewhere*.  Now, notice that the function is "symmetric in $a$ and $b$".  This means that if you swap the values of $a$ and $b$ in the function, the function itself does not change.  Graphically, that is equivalent to reflecting the parabola across a mirror halfway between $a$ and $b$.  The fact that the function is symmetric across that mirror tells us that the vertex of the parabola must be *on* that mirror -- which leads directly to the desired conclusion.

Comment: Nice use of symmetry in method 3.

Answer (score 1):

Without calculus:

Following user254665’s suggestion, expand, collect terms, and complete the square $$\begin{align}
(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2 &= x^2-2ax+a^2 + x^2-2bx+b^2 \\
&= 2x^2-2(a+b)x+(a^2+b^2) \\
&= 2\left(x^2-(a+b)x+\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2\right)-2\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2+(a^2+b^2) \\
&= 2\left(x-\frac{a+b}2\right)^2+\frac{(a-b)^2}2.
\end{align}$$
From here, you should be able to figure out where the non-negative term on the left has its minimum.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=2(x-a)+2(x-b)=4x-2(a+b)$ and $f''(x)=4$

**Theorem:** If $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)> 0$ then $c$ is a strict local minimum.

Now check this for $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$. Well, indeed, $f'(\frac{a+b}{2})=0$. CHECK! And indeed $f''(\frac{a+b}{2})=4>0$ CHECK! Thus, by the theorem, we may conclude that $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is indeed a strict *local* minimum (meaning you can find a neighborhood around $c$ such that $f(c)$ is indeed the minimum value that $f(x)$ takes in that neighborhood.

But we can say more! Since the $f'(x)\neq 0$ anywhere else on the real line, and the second derivative is strictly positive everywhere, we can safely conclude that $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is a *global* minimum of $f(x)$ on the real line. In other words, we found the smallest value that $f(x)$ takes on the whole real line (the domain), and that is at $c$.

Comment: Since the OP is pre-calculus, this solution is not very helpful.

Comment: @mweiss Just because OP is precalculus, that does not preclude knowledge of derivatives. I had learned this technique in my precalculus class. Voting down a correct and thorough answer based on your interpretation of OP's question despite the fact that they were not explicit in rejecting this method is simply WRONG!

Answer (score 0):

You probably know that a quadratic equation

$$y=Ax^2+Bx+C$$

can be represented by a parabola on the xy plane. You probably also know that if $A>0$ then it opens upwards and if $A<0$ then it opens downwards. Okay, so keeping that in mind, a parabola that opens upwards must have a minimum at the vertex.

Expanding your equation,
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&= (x-a)^2+(x-b)^2
\\
&=x^2 -2ax+a^2 + x^2 -2bx+b^2
\\
&=2x^2 -2(a+b)x+(a^2+b^2)
\end{align}
$$

we see that $A=2>0$, so it opens upwards and has a minimum.

Next you need to actually *find* the minimum. You may have learned vertex form (sometimes this goes by a different name):

$$y=c(x-h)^2+k,\quad\quad\text{where $(h,k)$ is the vertex}$$

If you can rewrite your given equation in vertex form, you can read off the vertex $(h,k)$, which is also your minimum. Good luck from here!

Hint:

> The process that I'm suggesting is called **completing the square.**